# How add more space in longtable

Tags: spacing, longtable

I'm using this code,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|p{.45\textwidth}|p{2em}|}\hline
\lipsum[1]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[2]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[3]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[2]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[1]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[3]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[5]&&\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which provides the below output

[image]

But I hope to have this:

[image]

Comment: `longtable` can have only a pagebreak _after_ a tabular line but not inside one.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the accumulated height on the previous page when longtable decides to page break? If the height is less than page height, add some vspace on the last line to tabular line, stretch it to the height of the page?

Comment: from provided images i don't see any difference. can you show only one, much bigger, from each series, from which we can see difference.

Comment: i hope each tabular is the same height but not in the Front

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\arraystretch`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,lipsum}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} %change 2 to different values as per your requirement
\begin{longtable}{|p{.5\textwidth}|p{.45\textwidth}|p{2em}|}\hline
\lipsum[1]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[2]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[3]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[2]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[1]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[3]&&\\\hline
\lipsum[5]&&\\\hline
\end{longtable}}
\end{document}
```